# Nobel laureates and where they currently work

Tags: university, academic-life

There are a lot of lists of Nobel laureates by institution available online. However I cannot find any that list laureates by where they are currently working.  Does such a list exist?

Comment: Since such a list would need continous actualisation, I doubt their existence.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog It could be updated as a wiki page I suppose. Or once a year alternatively,

Comment: I suspect many of them value their privacy - which they lose if such a list would be indeed published.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I value privacy too but isn't both the identity of all  Nobel laureates and the faculty list of all main universities public knowledge ?

Comment: Faculty lists are notoriously out of date. But there is a list of winners, I'm sure by the Nobel committee and you can then google the people and their faculty. Do not forget that also many of these winners may be retired and therefore may have changed affiliation.

Comment: A single list probably not but individual laureate are likely to have a wiki entry.